# How to detect if $_POST is set in Ajax calling PHP file

Tags: php, ajax

How to detect if `$_POST` is set in Ajax calling PHP file and check it?

Is there any way I can see the Ajax Flow!

Right now I detect it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['value']))
```

Updating value in DB or using Javascript Alert.

Comment: What's the question?  `isset($_POST['value'])` is how you check if a variable was `POST`ed or not.

Comment: Use Chrome, press Ctrl-Shift-I, select network tab and inspect your ajax traffic with headers (Form Data == POST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make in your PHP file like

`echo" <p id='detect'>"; echo (isset($_POST['foo'])) ? $_POST['foo'] :''; echo "</p>"`

Now, you could simply use Js, to detect if there is anything inside the `<p>` tag, using `innHTML`

```
var data = document.getElementById('detect').innerHTML;

if(data === ''){
 // means no post is made
}else{
 // post was made
}
```